# How to check request id is a page id or datasource id in code in Sitecore?

Tags: sxa, datasource

I want to check requested item id is a page item id or datasource item id through code. For more clarity, I have a scenario in SXA where we need to check requested id is page id or datasource id. If it is page item id then we will perform some activity or if it is datasource item id then we will perform some other activity.

Comment: There are multiple ways to find out a page item - 1. SXA has a Page template, so you can check if current item;s template is or inherited from page 2. If it has layout in presentation. For datasource item, it is difficult to generalize still anything that does not have layout and not created from Folder template can be a datasoruce item

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sitecore.Context.Item.ID`. This will return the current page item ID.
Use `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item.ID` will return the data source item ID. You can compare the ID with one of these and execute your code accordingly.

Regards,
Girish

Comment: I am getting item id but i am not sure how to identify this is page item id or datasource item id. I am using above mentioned code but i am getting error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to identify if the datasource item is a page or just a content item.  Ideally in Sitecore an item can be called a page if there is any presentation details associated with that item and this can be checked by using below code.

```
item.Visualization.GetLayout(Sitecore.Context.Device);
```

Above line of code will tell you if any presentation detail is associated with the item or not. If not then its a simple datasource item otherwise its a page.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is giving result null for the last datasource item only. However, if we have structure -:
Page>
    Data>
      Test>
           Accordion Item>
               Data>
                    Text 1
Then it is not giving the exact result. For this example the last "Text 1" showing null result. Here "Page" is a page item and other are datasource items

Comment: I suppose the presentation detail is only present on page item and for that you should get the layout item. But for other items like Data, Accordion Item and Text1  should give you null until you have assigned presentation detail to those items.

Comment: i have resolved this issue by checking page template id. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Atul Kumar's answer should work for you. An alternate way is to get item by ID

```
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(itemId));
```

and then pass the item to below func -

```
private bool HasPresentationDetails(Item item)
{
 return item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField] != null
      && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField].Value);
}
```

If it returns true, the item is a page item. Else it is a datasource item.